# Connection Refused error in Amazon AWS EC2 api call

Tags: php, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

***"org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://myurl.amazonaws.com Connection refused."***

Here I am using a web service uploaded in Amazon AWS EC2 server, which is used to upload a video. But on the start it throws an error of Connection refused. Api call is from Android App(method used is httpclienturlconnection & HttpClient, org.apache.httpcomponents gradle for it).  One another error also occurs that -> ***"Value org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"***. It just simply works in swift(IOS) but it gets stuck in Andorid(JAVA Base) with the same web service. Thank you in Advance.